# How to retreive specific aws region by providing the city name to aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am writing a small python function to know the `aws region` of our AWS EIPs. When I use the `ipinfo` services such as ipinfo.io, I do get these details:

```
~ ➤ curl ipinfo.io/18.138.84.13/json
{
  "ip": "18.138.84.13",
  "hostname": "ec2-18-138-84-13.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "region": "Singapore",
  "country": "SG",
  "loc": "1.2897,103.8501",
  "org": "AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc.",
  "postal": "048508",
  "timezone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}%
~ ➤
```

From this information, I get all the details except the `region_name`. Of course, I can trim the hostname URL to grep the region name i.e. `ap-southeast-1` but that is not optimal.

Is there any way in either `boto3` or `aws cli` where I can hit the aws API with params like `region=Singapore` and in response I get `ap-southeast-1`.

Or if there is any aws `api` I can hit directly by giving input as EIP and it return me details including `region_name`. I need to use `region_name` further in my script for automating the job.

Comment: I can do this: `hostname.rsplit('.', 4)[1]` and this gives me output as: `ap-southeast-1`. But I am just wondering if there is any better way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by this:

`hostname.rsplit('.', 4)[1]`

This hostname is in the response of `ipinfo.io/18.138.84.13/json`

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, IP addresses are assigned dynamically, they are not bounded by region, The eip pool will automatically you IP address which they have available. I would suggest to ignore the region base on ip address.

Comment: That's incorrect information, AWS EIPs are bounded with the region. Run the below command and see the output: `curl ipinfo.io/18.138.84.13/json`

Comment: My question is to have other information, like for `"region": "Singapore"` if I can also get `"region": "ap-southeast-1"`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question, but if you check the IP whois record you would see them assign to Amazon in US base on its AS Number, But if you reserve an EIP in your account you could use do hostname lookup from there you could get the the dns name from which you could get the region. Then you could store an Hashmap in your code for region-specific and do the matching.

For python3 you could `socket` library and `socket.gethostbyaddr()` function to get the dns, without calling the external website which does the same.

Comment: I can do `hostname.rsplit('.', 4)[1]` from ipinfo and that would anyway give me `region_name` what I am looking for i.e. `ap-southeast-1`. I just asked this question if somebody aware about any aws `api` which would give me result without triming the URL.